# How to use the trim function to trim inside of a list

Tags: c#, list, trim

I am trying to trim an item called Input (object form .json file) which is inside of a foreach loop.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
List<string> dhurl = new List<string>();

foreach (JObject item in jArray)
{
    dhurl.Add("https://" + (string)item.SelectToken("Input");
}
```

input adds "sm-tiktoktrends.com", I want it to only add "tiktoktrends.com", how can I use trim to remove "sm-"?

*To clarify all Input objects will need sm- removed

Comment: What makes you think `Trim` will be helpful for this specific problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not clear if all values start with "sm-".  If so, and you're willing to use LINQ:

```
List<string> dhurl = jArray.Select(item => "https://" + ((string)item.SelectToken("Input")).Substring(3)).ToList();
```

Otherwise, I might do it something like this:

```
List<string> dhurl = jArray
    .Select(item => (string)item.SelectToken("Input"))
    .Select(item => "https://" + (item.StartsWith("sm-") ? item.Substring(3) : item))
    .LoList();
```

New example based on comment below:

```
List<string> dhurl = jArray
    .Select(item =>
        string.Format(
            "https://{0}/?sig={1}",
            ((string)item.SelectToken("Input")).Substring(3),
            (string)item.SelectToken("Signature")
        ))
    .LoList();
```

Comment: This is helpful thank you. I have one more question to add to this. All the values for 'input' do start with sm- so I want to remove it before putting it into the foreach loop. I have just realised aswell that I will be adding a signature to the url eg. dhurl.Add("https://" + (string)item.SelectToken("Input") + "/?sig=" + (string)item.SelectToken("signature"));, how can I do this now?-

Comment: I added a new example for the signature.  I'm not sure what you mean by "before putting it into the foreach loop".  My examples don't have a `foreach` loop.  They are building a new list directly from the existing list.

Answer (score 1):

You, probably, should use `Substring(...)` together with `StartsWith(...)` instead of `Trim(...)`:

```
string input = item.SelectToken("Input").ToString();
if (input.StartsWith("sm-"))
{
    input = input.Substring(3);
}
dhurl.Add("https://" + input);
```

Answer (score 1):

`dhurl.Add($"https://{item.SelectToken("Input").Replace("sm-","")}")` ?

Comment: `Replace` will replace all occuriencies on "sm-", not only first one.

Comment: This does not work - it says "No overload for method 'Replace' takes 2 arguments